# ASP Identity custom password signin not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm currently trying to implement my own custom PasswordSignInAsync method on the ApplicationSignInManager, but so far it fails to authenticate even though the method won't throw any errors, here is my code in IdentityConfig.cs. I have already configured ASP Identity to use long as primary keys.

I don't know if I'm missing an additional operation for creating a correct user signin, could anyone point me what I'm missing, I haven't found any code for this. This custom function passes an additional parameter to the GenerateUserIdentityAsync method of the ApplicationUser.

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, long>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSystemSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool IsPersistent, bool shouldLockout, bool IsAdministrative, string securityCode = null)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            if(user != null)
            {
                bool passwordCheck = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
                if (passwordCheck)
                {
                    var signInUser = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager, IsAdministrative);
                    if (signInUser.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        return SignInStatus.Success;
                    }
                    return SignInStatus.Failure;
                }
                return SignInStatus.Failure;
            }
            return SignInStatus.Failure;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method you create the identity but you are not sign in the generated identity. Consider this:

```
public async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSystemSignInAsync(string userName,string password, bool IsPersistent, bool shouldLockout, bool IsAdministrative, string securityCode = null)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    if(user != null)
    {
        bool passwordCheck = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
        if (passwordCheck)
        {
            var userIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager, IsAdministrative);
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = IsPersistent}, userIdentity);
            return SignInStatus.Success;
        }
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
    }
    return SignInStatus.Failure;
}
```

Comment: What does the AuthenticationManager.signout do exactly? And on the SignIn do I have to set all properties? Does the method retrieves all other properties from Startup.Auth?

Comment: @Forcefield in order to make sure the user is not already signed in simply you could call the `signOut` method to sign out user. The method is safe and don't do anything if user did not sign in already, No you don't have to set all of the properties just fills once you want to alter.

Comment: This is the way to go! Just passing the IsPersistent from the parameter is the only change I would make to your answer. Does the Identity SignIn manager has this referenced somewhere? I couldn't find any examples of customized PasswordSignInMethod that didn't called the base one

Comment: Identity is an open source project you could check the [source code](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/)